# yajl_tree_get return 0 when path node name is the same

Tags: c, json, yajl

here is the JSON text:

```
{
    "retcode": 0,
    "result": {
        "info": [{
            "face": 180,
            "flag": 8913472,
            "nick": "tom",
            "uin": 2951718842
        }, {
            "face": 252,
            "flag": 512,
            "nick": "jim",
            "uin": 824317252
        }, {
            "face": 0,
            "flag": 17302018,
            "nick": "hanmeimei",
            "uin": 1179162105
        }, {
            "face": 522,
            "flag": 4719104,
            "nick": "lilei",
            "uin": 108219029
        }]
    }
}
```

below is the function to get "nick" node of the JSON text

```
char* getNickName()
{
    char* path[20] = { "result", "info", "nick", (char *) 0 }; 
    yajl_val v;
    yajl_val node;
    node = yajl_tree_parse(buffer, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
    v = yajl_tree_get(node, path, yajl_t_string);
    return YAJL_GET_STRING(v);
}
```

function `getNickName` should return **lilei** or similar stuff but in fact it always return 0.

as there is not only one node named "nick", so how can yajl parse "nick" one by one ?

how can I get the value like **tom** , **jim** etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need get **info** array firstly. then traversal the array.

```
char* path[20] = { "result", "info", (char *) 0 }; 
yajl_val v;
yajl_val info;
info = yajl_tree_parse(buffer, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
if (info && YAJL_IS_ARRAY(info)) {
    size_t len = info->u.array.len;
    for(int i = 0;i < len; i++) {
        const char *n_path[] = {"nick",(const char *)0};
        yajl_val n = yajl_tree_get(f,n_path,yajl_t_string);

        // here is what you need
        char *nickname = YAJL_GET_STRING(n);

}
```

DONE